# Select a Image from Multiple Images and Post to Wall using Graph API in Android

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

How to select an image from multiple images and then post to wall using Facebook Graph API in Android.

I know how to post a particular image to wall, but this time i want to know how allow user to post an image to wall from multiple image(s).

For an example :

```
  like now i want to show 4 Images (Image1, Image2, Image3, Image4) and let 
  user to select one of them to post to wall
```

I want to achieve this target by using any way, i am ready to use web image url or use drawable images, but i just want to make it... so need your help..thanks in advance

Code to post a Particular image to wall:

```
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                Bundle params = new Bundle();

                                params.putString("picture", 
                                        FacebookUtility.HACK_ICON_URL); 
                            }
```